# Why does my pycharm debug console output not show proper diff from pytest

Tags: python, powershell, debugging, pycharm, pytest

I'm writing python 3.7 on windows via Pycharm. I have always used a separate terminal window to run my tests, but I'm currently trying out the native pycharm test runner. I've run into one problem that is really bothering me.

If I have this test:

```
def test__output_test():
    assert ['123\n', '456\n', '789\n'] == ['123\n', '455\n', '789\n']
```

When I run it via command line directly in powershell with `python -m pytest -vv <path>`, I get this lovely output:

```
    def test__output_test():
>       assert ['123\n', '456\n', '789\n'] == ['123\n', '455\n', '789\n']
E       AssertionError: assert ['123\n', '456\n', '789\n'] == ['123\n', '455\n', '789\n']
E         At index 1 diff: '456\n' != '455\n'
E         Full diff:
E         - ['123\n', '455\n', '789\n']
E         ?              ^
E         + ['123\n', '456\n', '789\n']
E         ?              ^
```

But when I run the same test via the pycharm's pytest test runner (-vv is set in "Additional Arguments"), the output seems to truncate the actual diff display:

```
def test__output_test():
>       assert ['123\n', '456\n', '789\n'] == ['123\n', '455\n', '789\n']
E       AssertionError: assert ['123\n', '456\n', '789\n'] == ['123\n', '455\n', '789\n']

..\tests\unit\test__output.py:4: AssertionError
```

There seems to be an attempt at a diff above the test result output, but it's terrible compared to what I get in powershell:

```
FAILED                  [100%]
unit\test__output.py:2 (test__output_test)
['123
', '456
', '789
'] != ['123
', '455
', '789
']

<Click to see difference>
```

The diff viewer that pops up if I click the "see difference" link is "ok", as it will highlight the modified words/symbols, but it still messes up the quoted newline characters

I tried to set my pycharm terminal to powershell, but that didn't change the debug console output at all. I'm wondering if there's some additional argument or setting I need to set to see my preferred diffs?

Comment: It's no terminal, but PyCharm's UI that does that. You can open a new feature proposal about it at JetBrains' tracker or (probably) implement it yourself if the component is part of  the [community edition](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community).